# Cordova sendJavascript not working for android processMessage failed: Error: not defined:10

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building a phonegap-android application and as a part of the flow, I am calling an activity from my javascript side using javascriptInterface

This looks like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");

        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());


}
```

now I also want to send back some data from my activity to the cordova webview.

I have defined a function in my javascript file which I want to call

```
function jsi_getData(data) {
     console.log("JSI GET IMAGE INVOKED ON JAVASCRIPT SIDE");
     alert(data);
 }
```

and in my android code, inside onActivityResult, I am calling this javascript function

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if(requestCode == 12321){
             //do some work

           Log.i("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "***************  received data"+ data);
            appView.sendJavascript("javascript:jsi_getImage("+data+");");

        }
    }
```

This gives me the following error

```
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991): processMessage failed: Message: Jjavascript:jsi_getData('data');:1034
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991): processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: jsi_getImage is not defined:1035
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991): processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: jsi_getImage is not defined
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991):     at eval (eval at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/cordova.js:996:26), <anonymous>:1:1)
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991):     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/cordova.js:996:13)
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991):     at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/cordova.js:1063:13)
09-16 18:18:27.211: I/Web Console(28991):     at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/cordova.js:933:17):1036
09-16 18:18:27.481: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(28991): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
```

I also changed a`appView.sendJavascript()` to `this.sendJavascript()` and I still have the same error
Please help as I am litrally stuck!! This would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue and I was going MENTAL with it, finally I found came up with an "UGLY" but working solution:

Instead of passing the data back from the onActivityResult do the following.

1) Define a global variable in your JAVA and store the result in that global variable

2) DO this in the onActivityResult:

```
Log.i("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "***************  received data"+ data);
appView.sendJavascript("jsi_getImage();");
```

3) Define another function in you JAVA something like:

```
public String send_picture() {
return previously_defined_global_variable;
}
```

4) In your Javascript function called jsi_getImage, make another call to send_picture() like:

```
function jsi_getImage(){
alert(window.MainActivity.send_picture());
}
```

Make sure that you are sending only string data between Java and Javascript (BASE64 encode for image)

Hope it helps